# What process is accessing a mounted filesystem sporadically?

Tags: filesystems, solaris, open-files, autofs

I have a Solaris 10 server with autofs-mounted home dirs. On one server they are not unmounted after the 10 min timeout period. We've got `AUTOMOUNT_TIMEOUT=600` in `/etc/default/autofs`, I ran `automount -t 600`, disabled and re-enabled `svc:/system/filesystem/autofs:default` service and nothing seems to work.

My suspicion is that *something* on the system is periodically accessing all the mounted filesystems, maybe checking if they are accessible, and thus resetting the automounter timeout that in turn never expires. This is supported by a test I just did - if I set the timeout to 10 seconds the mountpoints are unmounted, looks like 10 sec is shorter than the period in which that *something* is doing the checks and the timer has a chance to expire.

The question is how can I find what process is doing that? The server is a heavily used production system and I can't do any dangerous experiments on it.

Note that the filesystems are *not* kept open and can be manually unmounted. That *something* is probably going mountpoint by mountpoint, cd in, cd out, move on, often enough to prevent `automount` from unmounting it. But it doesn't keep it open and therefore is not visible with `lsof` or `fuser -c`. I want to catch it or record it as soon as it accesses the mountpoints to know what's doing it.

FWIW it's a Solaris 10 zone on rather beefy Solaris 10 host (Sparc / M5000).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try rwsnoop (http://dtracebook.com/index.php/File_System:rwsnoop) to monitor i/o access using dtrace:

```
# rwsnoop - snoop read/write events.
#           Written using DTrace (Solaris 10 3/05).
#
# This is measuring reads and writes at the application level. This matches
# the syscalls read, write, pread and pwrite.
```

good luck!

Comment: That looks promising, thanks! I don't want to filter by PID, instead by mountpoint, but will take that script as a starting point. Thanks again!

Comment: the script outputs the path, so you can always use grep to filter the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tool `lsof` to determine what process is accessing a particular file on the filesystem. In this case you can use it to detect what process is accessing the automount's mount point.

#### Example

I have the following `automount` for my `/vz_backups` directory:

```
$ showmount -e krycek
Export list for krycek:
/export/raid1/vz_backups 192.168.1.0/24
```

Now cd to an automount under the mount point:

```
$ cd /vz_backups/images
```

See that we've mounted it:

```
$ mount | grep /vz
krycek:/export/raid1/vz_backups/images on /vz_backups/images type nfs (rw,intr,tcp,rsize=16384,wsize=16384,addr=192.168.1.4)
```

You can then interrogate file accesses using `lsof`:

```
$ lsof -l | grep /vz
automount  3359        0   16r      DIR       0,24           0      11960 /vz_backups
bash      28635        0  cwd       DIR       0,30        4096    2981890 /vz_backups/images (krycek:/export/raid1/vz_backups/images)
lsof      31040        0  cwd       DIR       0,30        4096    2981890 /vz_backups/images (krycek:/export/raid1/vz_backups/images)
grep      31041        0  cwd       DIR       0,30        4096    2981890 /vz_backups/images (krycek:/export/raid1/vz_backups/images)
lsof      31042        0  cwd       DIR       0,30        4096    2981890 /vz_backups/images (krycek:/export/raid1/vz_backups/images)
```

Now `cd` out of that directory so that nothing is accessing it, and either wait for the automount to timeout, or manually `umount` it and then check it again:

```
$ cd ~
$ umount /vz_backups/images

$ lsof -l | grep /vz
automount  3359        0   16r      DIR       0,24           0      11960 /vz_backups
```

#### References

- [Finding open files with lsof](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-lsof.html)
- [lsof man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof)

Comment: Thanks for that but it's not that simple. Trouble is there is no process that has the mountpoint permanently open (therefore `lsof` or even simpler `fuser -c /mount/point/` comes out empty). I *suspect* that from time to time some process goes bang bang gang one filesystem after another, cd in, cd out, move on. Therefore I need to catch or record it when it does so. I don't know what is it nor how often it accesses the mountpoints. That's what I want to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have monitoring software running which runs the 'df' command in an interval lower than your automounter timeout. On Solaris, the statvfs system call marks a filesystem as in use. Solution : use `df -l`.